# Why can't I externally access the example Istio endpoint when using a namespace? (w/ minikube)

Tags: istio, minikube

I am following the instructions provided [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started) using minikube. The main difference is I am doing everything in the 'test' namespace. Everything looks to be correct I get an IP and a port...

```
~/Code/lib/tmp >echo "http://$GATEWAY_URL/productpage"                                      
http://192.168.49.2:31914/productpage
```

But when I try to access that in the browser it times out. I did notice in the gateway-spec it is pointing at 8080...

```
~/Code/lib/tmp >kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports}'
[{"name":"status-port","nodePort":31745,"port":15021,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":15021},{"name":"http2","nodePort":31914,"port":80,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":8080},{"name":"https","nodePort":31244,"port":443,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":8443},{"name":"tcp","nodePort":30472,"port":31400,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":31400},{"name":"tls","nodePort":32306,"port":15443,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":15443}]%
```

Whereas the gateway on the namespace side is using 9080...

```
route:
- destination:
    host: productpage
    port:
      number: 9080
```

But I also could be off base. The response I get is...

> The server at 192.168.49.2 is taking too long to respond.

*Gateway*

```
~/Code/lib/tmp >kubectl describe Gateway bookinfo-gateway -n test                              
Name:         bookinfo-gateway
Namespace:    test
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  networking.istio.io/v1beta1
Kind:         Gateway
Metadata:
  ...
Spec:
  Selector:
    Istio:  ingressgateway
  Servers:
    Hosts:
      *
    Port:
      Name:      http
      Number:    80
      Protocol:  HTTP
Events:          <none>
~/Code/lib/tmp >kubectl get Gateway -n test                                                    
NAME               AGE
bookinfo-gateway   33m
```

*Update*

I tried using a simple load balancer like

```
kubectl expose deployment productpage-v1 --type=LoadBalancer --port=9080 -n test
```

This works fine going to `localhost:9080`

```
~/Code/lib/tmp >kubectl get services -n test 
NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
details          ClusterIP      10.103.184.105   <none>        9080/TCP         6h43m
productpage      ClusterIP      10.109.150.132   <none>        9080/TCP         6h43m
productpage-v1   LoadBalancer   10.98.252.50     127.0.0.1     9080:32172/TCP   14s
ratings          ClusterIP      10.98.189.253    <none>        9080/TCP         6h43m
reviews          ClusterIP      10.106.74.190    <none>        9080/TCP         6h43m
```

So it must be something from the Istio side.

## Update 2

The Gateway and Virtual Service are both on the test namespace...

```
~/Code/lib/tmp >kubectl get GATEWAY -A
NAMESPACE   NAME               AGE
test        bookinfo-gateway   4m52s
~/Code/lib/tmp >kubectl get virtualservice -A
NAMESPACE   NAME       GATEWAYS               HOSTS   AGE
test        bookinfo   ["bookinfo-gateway"]   ["*"]   5m3s
```

Here are the list of steps I followed...

```
minikube delete
minikube start --memory=16384 --cpus=4 --kubernetes-version=v1.20.2
istioctl install --set profile=demo -y
Kubectl create namespace test
kubectl label namespace test istio-injection=enabled
kubectl apply -f bookinfo.yml -n test
kubectl apply -f bookinfo-gateway.yml -n test
istioctl analyze -n test
export INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http2")].nodePort}')
export SECURE_INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="https")].nodePort}')
export INGRESS_HOST=$(minikube ip)
minikube tunnel (separate window)
```

Here is what happens with the tunnel command...

```
~ >minikube tunnel
❗  The service/ingress istio-ingressgateway requires privileged ports to be exposed: [80 443]
  sudo permission will be asked for it.
  Starting tunnel for service istio-ingressgateway.
Password:
```

After I enter my password there is no more text. It does seem to be running because when I ctrl+c it stops the command.

Comment: Are your VirtualService and Gateway in the same namespace?

Comment: Yes I can post the commands to prove it

Comment: Sure, it won't hurt. If you can, please also add full VirtualService and Gateway manifests. There may be some issues there.

Comment: The manifests should be available via a link in the example (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.13/samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml)

Comment: @p10l added the requested information

Comment: I deleted minikube and started all over again with the same result. Could it be the version of minikube or kubectl I am using? Minikube is 1.24.0 and Kubectl is 1.22.5 but the k8s used is 1.20.2

Comment: If it is that is there a way to debug it and confirm vs. just assuming that is the case?

Comment: Looks like 1.22.5 should be supported given I am using 1.13 of istio (https://istio.io/latest/docs/releases/supported-releases/)

Comment: Pretty sure the instructions are just wrong for minikube. Got it working using 127.0.0.1 instead of the Gatway URL

Comment: Would you mind posting an answer how you got this to work? I've hit the same issue